# Do "in a black study" and "in a brown study" mean the same?

Tags: expressions

I encountered relatively often the expression "to be in a brown study" but I can find nothing about the "black" version of the same expression. I found it in William Hope Hodgson's The Island of the Crossbones. I believe the meaning should be the same -at least he's talking about someone who's quite pensive- but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Black study* has occasionally been used as an 'intensive' version of 'brown study' since the end of the 18th century—usually with specific reference to the older expression. The earliest versions I have found are these:

> ... his pen was across his mouth, and his brown wig pushed obliquely upon his contracted forehead—the wig was always pushed crooked whenever he was in a brown, or rather a black study.  —Maria Edgworth, *Parent’s Assistant*, 1796
>
> At the appointed time, Dinah tapped at my door, came in, and continued, for a minute or two, in a brown, or as my good father used to say, when he noticed any thing of the kind in the servants, a black study.   —Q. E. D., “A Couple of Love-Letters”, *Southern Literary Messenger*, March, 1838

Answer (score 1):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20a%20brown%20study%2C%20in%20a%20black%20study&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20brown%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20black%20study%3B%2Cc0) shows very small evidence of the expression *'in a black study*' ( whatever its meaning) and it appears that there is no reference about it meaning the same as 'in a brown study'.

I think that the use of it instead of *in a brown study* should  be considered as author specific.

[In a brown study](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/19/messages/327.html):

> Being in a brown study means deep in thought, and more often than not, deep in unhappy or depressing thoughts. *According to the American Heritage Dictionary, it comes from brown as in a figurative sense of gloomy, and study, which among many other things can mean "a state of mind or mental absorbtion".*
>
> - "Lack of company will soon lead a man into a brown study." Whether or not it's true, that [*Dice-Play*,] 1532 admonition is the first known example that shows the "reverie" sense of "study" combined with "brown" (in the old and now rare sense, "gloomy"). Today, not all brown studies are "gloomy" -- some are merely abstracted -- but not, we hope, to the extent that provoked the editors of an encyclopedia of the 1950s to call it "a state nearly related to hypnosis and characterized by the ... arrest of bodily movement."
>     From Merriam-Webster's Word of the Day (March 12, 2000)

Source: The Phrase Finder.

Comment: I think your quote answers the question "what's the difference?" It says "brown studies" today need not be gloomy. I don't believe anybody would use "black study" if they did not intend to imply gloom.